# Deleting a marker from google maps with custom delete button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, onclick

I am trying to delete a marker from google maps through a custom delete button. I have added the button and other information in the infowindow. 
I have a function which deletes the marker from the map, the problem is when I press the delete button the function isnt called.

Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {

var jsonData = {$pointsArray};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
       maxzoom: 15,
        center: {
           lat: 38,
           lng: -77
         }
     });

 function addInfoWindow(marker, message) {

         var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
             content: message
         });

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
             infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         });
     }

 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 for (var i = 0, len = jsonData.length; i < len; ++i) {

    var point = jsonData[i];
    var uniqueId = 1;
    var  markers = [];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(point.Lat, point.Lon),
        map: map,
        title: point.Title
    });

 bounds.extend(marker.position);
 marker.id = uniqueId;
         uniqueId++;

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                     '<h4 id="pointId" > ' + point.Title + '</h4>'+
                     '<h6 >City: ' + point.City + '</h6>'+
                     '<h6 >Latitude: ' + point.Lat+ '</h6>'+
                     '<h6 >Longitude: ' + point.Lon + '</h6>'+
                     '<h6 >Address: ' + point.Address + '</h6>'+
                     '<p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><a href="" onclick= "DeleteMarker( "+ marker.id +"  );"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p>'

                    '</div>';
    addInfoWindow(marker, contentString);
    markers.push(marker);
 }

 function DeleteMarker(id) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].id == id) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
            markers.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
};

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
 }
```

Probably there is something wrong with the onclick attribute in the delete button, but I am not sure.
Help!

Comment: what is called when you press the button? i.e. code for the button, please.

Comment: maybe this answer helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31496676/3592827

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use ' instead of " when you want to give marker.id as parameter because you used ' for the string and " for the attribute value. If you use " you just interrupt the attribute string for the onclick value.

Comment: I tried that as well but that gives me a syntax error while Debugging. 
I changed it to this:  'DeleteMarker(" + marker.id + ");'  ,  doesnt work.

Comment: If you have a string which starts with ' and you want to use ' a second time in the string you have to use \'  for example like this '......onclick= "DeleteMarker(\' '+ marker.id + ' \'  );".....'

Answer (score 0):

In the rendered html, your function should look like this:

```
<p><a onclick="DeleteMarker('some id');"</a></p>
```

In order to achive that, put additional single quotes around the your id parameter:

`onclick="deleteMarker('+"'"+ yourId +"'"+')`